How to set a property of an object to the reference of an element in an array?
I'm trying to point the value of a property to an array element, which will be set at a later time. I have the following code:
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    private static string[] s = new string[] { null };
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.Value = s[0];
        Console.WriteLine ("value bef = " + a.Value);
        s[0] = "test";
        Console.WriteLine ("value aft = " + a.Value);
    }
    
    public class A
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}

When I run the code above, I get the following output:
value bef = 
value aft = 

However, since C# works with strings with references, I expected the output to be
value bef = 
value aft = test

Why does this not work? Is there anyway I can do this in C#? Converting A.Value to a class or s to an array of As is not really an option.

Why don't you store the whole A object in the array instead of just a string?

Because references to objects in s must be shared. A has other properties that can't be shared. For example, var a and another var b might both point to s[0] for Value property. But rest of the properties of A shouldn't be shared.

A reference to a string is just a variable like an integer. It's a value, but it's a value that represents a location. Two variables can have the same reference, but when you change one of the variable's reference you're only changing that one variable. The other reference remains the same.


since C# works with strings with references, I expected ...

At the time of the first console output, s[0] and a.Value are both, yes, reference variables that happen to contain null for the reference values.
But they are different variables, and it doesn't matter that one was initialized with the other. You can change one variable or the other without changing both, because a.Value is given an empty reference for null. It is not given a reference to the s[0] variable.
So when then assigning "test" to s[0], you changed that variable to refer to a new  string object, but the a.Value variable still has the same null reference as before.
It also doesn't matter whether the initial value is null or an actual string object. The result is the same either way.

But what if the s array held references to our A class?
private static A[] s = new A[] { null };

Then I'll change up the code just a bit so we  have a value to work with:
var a = new A();
s[0] = a; // reversed the assignment
Console.WriteLine ("value bef = " + a.Value); // Shows "value bef = "
s[0].Value = "test"; // s[0] is an A object now, so we set it's property
Console.WriteLine ("value aft = " + a.Value); // Shows "value aft = test"

And so we're clear, we could also have done this:
// create the object here
private static A[] s = new A[] { new A() };

A a = new A();
a.Value = s[0]; // but keep the original assignment
Console.WriteLine ("value bef = " + a.Value); // Shows "value bef = "
s[0].Value = "test";
Console.WriteLine ("value aft = " + a.Value); // Shows "value aft = test"

For both of these, the change is shown. The reason is because both s[0] and a are set to refer to the same object. They are still different variables, but they have references to the same item. We then change a property on that one single object, rather than the object reference itself. It's the same object, but with a different value for the property, so both variables will still show the same result.

The code will work in this form:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
    a.Value = ref s[0]; // <- ref
    Console.WriteLine("value bef = " + a.Value);
    s[0] = "test";
    Console.WriteLine("value aft = " + a.Value);
}

public ref struct A
{
    public ref string Value;
}


Okay... but don't do this.

Hmmm with this any changes made to a.Value will directly affect the value of s[0], essentially making s[0] mutable through a.Value. A more predictable way would be having a private member field in class A.

Because object String is immutable.
s[0] = "test"; 

s[0] will not be modified, but creat a new string object at another memory location.
a.Value is still point to the original object which is null.
